# How do I get this for loop to return the dataframe broken up based on the ranges?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a program that will sort a dataframe based on a given range and return a subsets of the original dataframe. The range can be variable for the example I just 3. And the issue I'm having is when I try to split up dataframe the first range is the only one that is printed.

I have tried & statement, I am currently using .between, I have tried to add if statements and break and continue but none have achieved what I am after .between has come closest

```
data = { 'a':[3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 2.0], 'b':[1, 3, 5, 3], 'c':[2, 4, 6, 8]}
range = [(0,2), (3,5), (6,8)]

def sort_a(range, data):
    for item in (range):
        low, high = item
        data = data[data['a'].between(low, high)]
        print(data)
```

Expected

```
   a    b   c  
0  2.0  3   8


   a    b   c
0  3.0  1   2
1  5.0  3   4

   a    b   c
0  7.0  5   6
```

Actual

```
   a    b   c  
0  2.0  3   8
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

Comment: What is `'age'` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'a':[3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 2.0], 'b':[1, 3, 5, 3], 'c':[2, 4, 6, 8]}
r = [(0,2), (3,5), (6,8)]

df =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
for rr in r:
    data1 = df[df['a'].between(*rr)]
    print(data1)
```

you get your expected output:

```
     a  b  c
3  2.0  3  8
     a  b  c
0  3.0  1  2
1  5.0  3  4
     a  b  c
2  7.0  5  6
```

This is answer is similar to the one already given, your issue is that you are rewriting the data frame when you do `data = data[data['a'].between(low, high)]`. However, I changed the name of your `range` variable to r. Do not name variables the same name as built in functions (`range` is a built in function). You can also just use the asterisk with `item` in the `.between` function, you don't need to assign variable names and then put them in.

you can store them in a dict too , just to refer to them later on:

```
d={f'df_{e}': df[df['a'].between(*rr)] for e,rr in enumerate(r)}
print(d['df_1'])
```

---

```
     a  b  c
0  3.0  1  2
1  5.0  3  4
```

Comment: i edited with some inputs that I had, hope you are okay with it, if any improvements, kindly edit :)

Comment: Thanks so much Anna! For bonus points, how would I get these to return to my main function?

Comment: use @anky_91 's idea of storing it to a dictionary, and return d!

Answer (score 2):

You are rewriting data,  try this:

```
data2 = data[data['a'].between(low, high)] 
print(data2)
```